# uninstalling msi deleting apppools

Tags: iis-7, wix, windows-installer

i  have one  wcf service project  msi . I am generating MSI by Wix and assigning the appool . but when i am uninstalling the msi . the app pool is also getting deleted even other virtual directory having the reference of that apppool .

if some one know please help me on that ..

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to locate the problem if you paste the code you use to work with AppPool in WiX. I assume you nest the `<iis:WebAppPool>` element under the `<Component>` element. In this case the application pool will be created during install, and removed during the uninstall. Even if it was there by the time of the installation, it will still be removed.

You should locate the `<iis:WebAppPool>` under the `Product` or `Module` or `Fragment` element. In this case it will serve as a *locator*, allowing other elements reference it, but not being installed / uninstalled.

Take a look at the [element description](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_webapppool.htm) for more details. The trick with *locator* behavior of the element is described in [`<WebSite>` element article](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_website.htm).

Answer (score 0):

If the virtual directories that share that application pool are in different MSI's, you need to read up on the concepts of the component rules and shared components.  This way MSI will reference count the component and remove it and it's resources when it's approriate.

Otherwise I typically just create more app pools to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other two answers. Im my case I wanted the WebAppPool to stay were it is after uninstall. So if you want to install the WebAppPool in your msi and stay after uninstall you can add a "Permanent" attribute to your "Component" tag and set its value to "yes" like this:

```
<Component Id="RepoAppPoolCmp" Guid="{B676B577-FEDB-44BF-9096-1510D2A29E38}" KeyPath="yes" Permanent="yes">
    <iis:WebAppPool Id="RepoAppPool" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" IdleTimeout="0" RecycleMinutes="0" Name="[WEB_APP_POOL_IDENTITY]" Identity="networkService" />
</Component>
```

This should make the deal.